# Validating Combo box in vba 7.1

Tags: vba, validation, combobox, ms-access-2013

I am trying to validate a series of combo boxes on an access form so that a user cannot leave them blank when they process the form. I have tried using a variety of examples but am getting the same error - 'Expected end of statement'

Probably something very easy. The code example I have been playing with is:

```
Private Sub Combobox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As  System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles Combobox1.Validating
    If Combobox1.Items.Contains(Combobox1.Text) = False Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Combobox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Combobox1.Leave
    If Combobox1.Items.Contains(Combobox1.Text) = False Then
        Combobox1.Select()
        MessageBox.Show("select item from combobox")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not VBA - VB.NET?

Comment: Yeah, Tim has this one pegged. You are getting that error because there is no such statement as `Handles` in VBA (at the end of the Sub declarations)

Also, the `sender As Object, e As ....` in the parentheses are not doing anything for you. You can delete them.

But, this is VB.Net, not VBA, so none of this is a properly structured event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Change the MatchRequired property:

[image]

In whatever you are using for an OK button, you can add this code:

```
If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Nice try, now fill the combo box in right this time!")
    Exit Sub
end if
```

...and discard all of that VB.Net code!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try - VB in any shape or form is not my forte, I am trying to help solve a student's problem with their database.

Comment: I have tried adding the above as an 'On exit' action but still no joy - although the error is now 'Invalid outside procedure' - frustrating as I am struggling to know how to troubleshoot this as a problem not knowing VB.

Comment: When you click "debug" on that error message, what line is highighted? Could you also paste the entire sub/function that you are using in an edit to your original question please? Also, where is the code you are using? I presume that you are in the VBA editor, you have a userform, and you are editing the code behind that form. If you are somewhere else in access, I'll need to know.

Comment: As an update to your message - I now no longer have an error message but the code is not generating a message:

Comment: As an update to your message - I now no longer have an error message but the code is not generating a message. This code is in a userform, which uses 3 combo boxes to select suitable records in order to update data tables by reducing stock levels and adding to an orders table. Hope this helps

Comment: Private Sub Patient_ID_Combo_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
            If Patient_ID_Combo.Value = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Nice try, now fill the combo box in right this time!")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End Sub

Comment: And are you testing it where the combo box literally contains the value 0? If you are putting the code there, you also need to add cancel = True in between if... Then and end if.

Answer (score 0):

Problem now solved using the following code - thanks for all your contributions

```
Private Sub Process_Button_Click()

If Patient_ID_Combo.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox ("Nice try, now fill the combo box in right this time!")
End If
If Doctor_ID_combo.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please choose a Doctor")
End If
If Product_combo.ListIndex = -1 Then
    MsgBox ("Please choose a product")   
Else
    MsgBox ("You are about to update your records press ok to continue")
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update Stock", , acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "Update Prescriptions", , acAdd
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```